# CSP ionic resource load blocked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, content-security-policy

I am trying to load a resource in json format from a service on another pc, but I cannot get through and get a CSP error and the resource doesnt load. When I tried to connect to an online source (reddit), it worked just fine and returned me a json item.

my index.html's head

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ionic App</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://*http://192.168.201.55:8100data: gap:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';media-src *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://*http://pc_lesmes:8088data: gap:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';media-src *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
<!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker<script>if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(() => console.log('service worker installed')).catch(err => console.error('Error', err));}</script>-->
<link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I am trying to connect to this pc_lesmes's service but my firefox's console shows an error, pointing out "unvalid host cannot be interpreted" and "options for this page have prevented the load of a resource from pc_lesmes" Please note these are not the literall error codes but a translation.

What should I do in order to fix it? Also, ¿Do you know any reliable source for learning more about CSP? Thank you very much for your answers and time.

**EDIT**: If you downvote me, please let me know what am I doing wrong since I have not found any related threads and im trying to follow the guidelines.

Comment: Please always post your exact error message.

Comment: Its in spanish, but the message in english would be "unvalid host cannot be interpreted" followed by "csp: options for this page blocked resource load from pc_lesmes"

Comment: Alright, you might want to check out https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/ for a good introduction to CSP

Comment: Your CSP might be lacking whitespaces. Have you tried to use the following: `file://* http://192.168.201.55:8100 data:`. And have you double checked that `http://192.168.201.55:8100` is the correct ip and port of your service on another pc?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by setting the CSP to report only. I still cannot access the json because of CORS, but I think that is server-sided. I will ask the service's owner to put in a CORS header.

Comment: Turning off CSP is a stopgap, but not a good solution. See @Phonolog ‘s comment regard by white space — you have all you CSP directives pushes up against each other; they need spaces between them